# I'm receiving a DDOS attack. What to do?

Tags: ddos

Yesterday, my website bandwidth got over. After seeing the logs I saw this
[image]

This request came every 1 second (Different IP's).

Luckily I use Cloudflare. So my question is what are the other things that can I do to prevent such attacks?

Comment: You can't *prevent* the attacks, you can only respond to them.